# How do I assign the uploaders User ID to an image when uploading to the databse? (PHP MySQL)

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm doing an e-commerce site for a school project. I'm trying to figure out how to assign the uploaders ID when they are uploading an image to be inserted into the database to be fetched later if other users on a different account were to search images uploaded by that specific uploader, as I need to make a buy and sell website platform by changing the image to a product file. But to make it easier, I'll start with trying to make it work with images first.

I manage to create a workable search function by searching the category of the image as well. Now the problem I'm facing is if the way I'm assigning the user ID to the image is correct. I have a seperate DB for products and users, and I am thinking if to make it work I should also place both the User and Product tables into one DB?

This is my initial code altered from a tutorial to upload files provided its not empty

```
 // if no error occured, continue ....
    if(!isset($errMSG))
    {
        $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('INSERT INTO product_tbl(productName, productPrice,productPic,productDescription,productCategory) VALUES(:pname, :pprice, :ppic, :pdesc, :pcat)');
        $stmt->bindParam(':pname',$productname);
        $stmt->bindParam(':pprice',$productprice);
        $stmt->bindParam(':ppic',$productpic);
        $stmt->bindParam(':pdesc',$productdesc);
        $stmt->bindParam(':pcat',$productcategory);

        if($stmt->execute())
        {
            $successMSG = "new record succesfully inserted ...";
            header("refresh:5;products.php"); // redirects image view page after 5 seconds.
        }
        else
        {
            $errMSG = "error while inserting....";
        }
    }
```

What I have possibly come up with is to create a similar function such as:

```
$uID = $_POST['user_ID'];

$stmt = $DB_con->prepare('INSERT INTO product_tbl(userID, productName, ...) 
VALUES(:uID, :pname, .., :..)');
        $stmt->bindParam(':uID',$userID);
```

Is this a proper method to insert the users ID in association with the uploaded file?

sorry i am recently required to learn php at a fast paced .

**this is what my database looks like**

[for products files details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoPIy.png),
[for user registration details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYgoP.png)

they are both in a separate database

Comment: what is your database tables look like? Are there two tables one for users and one for files?

Comment: what is user_id in $_POST

Comment: @WaqarHaider, I created a separate table called products to store the file details (ID, Image. Description) but the images of the files are kept locally, and another separate database called register to store User details (username, password) as an initial database when I was learning how to create a user registration site.

Comment: add `user_id` column to the product details store and when you are adding product add user_id withit

Comment: @WaqarHaider the last section of the code is an idea I had to assign the uID to user_ID like the others such as.

$productname = $_POST['product_name'];

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Comment: yep, foreign keys.  Show us your tables structure in the question, what you have up to now.

Comment: hello @Nic, i have already added pictures for my tables

Comment: @WaqarHaider thank you for the link i will check it out on foreign keys

Comment: What I would do is create a third table where you would have: primary key == some auto-increment id.  Foreign key 1 == user id.  Foreign key 2 == product id.  Column 1 = productPic.  I would also split productCategory into another table.  But we are getting into database design and normalization, I do not know how far you want to go for this school project.  You could just add the user ID in the product table and not be normalized.

Comment: @nic, alright I will keep your advice at mind and try again!  thank you